# Localisation for Square In-App Payments SDK

Tags: ios, square

I've successfully integrated the new [In-App Payments SDK](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/in-app-payments-sdk/build-on-ios) into my iOS app, but I can't seem to find any localisation options... specifically, around the requirement to enter the ZIP code. My users are all UK-based, so the concept of a ZIP code might be alien to them.

Am I missing something somewhere? In some of the screenshots its shows 'Postal' in this field, but I'm getting 'ZIP' whether I try on the simulator or my device (which will have a en_GB locale active)...? I've looked around the `SQIPTheme` but there doesn't seem any obvious API.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time Square's In-App Payments SDK requires ZIP/Postal code to process payments. For en_GB you should be able to see Postal instead of ZIP by setting the **Application Language** in your scheme configurator and **Localizations** in your project settings to *"English (United Kingdom)"*. We also created a [GitHub branch](https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-ios-quickstart/commit/bde767b811b23ef80b0da40ab405b67801f48e8d) on how to change ZIP to Postal for GB.

We're working on the localization options for In-App Payments SDK, but right now we don’t have a timeline to share on its availability. Thank you for your feedback!